# Синтаксическая ошибка: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске следующей программы в конце выдается сообщение:

> SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой.

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
>>> print("Программа вычисления вероятности построения данной таблицы")

a=int(input("Input a: "))
b=int(input("Input b: "))
c=int(input("Input c: "))
d=int(input("Input d: "))

ac==a+c
bd==b+d
ab==a+b
cd==c+d
abcd==a+b+c+d
i=1
suma=0
sumb=0
sumc=0
sumd=0
sumac=0
sumbd=0
sumab=0
sumcd=0
sumabcd=0
sumln=0
exp=0
probability=0

import math

while i <= a:
    suma = suma+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= b:
    sumb = sumb+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= c:
    sumc = sumc+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= d:
    sumd = sumd+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= ac:
    sumac = sumac+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= bd:
    sumbd = sumbd+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= ab:
    sumab = sumab+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= cd:
    sumcd = sumcd+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

while i <= abcd:
    sumabcd = sumabcd+math.log(i)
    i = i+1

sumln=sumac+sumbd+sumab+sumcd-sumabcd-suma-sumb-sumc-sumd

probability=math.exp(sumln)

print ("probability: "+str(probability))
```

Comment: Василий, скажите строчку

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в этих строках:

```
ac==a+c
bd==b+d
ab==a+b
cd==c+d
abcd==a+b+c+d
```

нужно писать:

```
ac = a + c
bd = b + d
ab = a + b
cd = c + d
abcd = a + b + c + d
```

`==` — это оператор сравнения. `=` — оператор присвоения.